# Four Listviews in a single layout scroll

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, scroll

Myy linearLayout contains four textviews and four listviews. The problem is that only two listviews are visible on the screen, if i want to scroll down the second listview starts scrolling not the whole layout. I've tried putting them in a scrollView but they got all collapsed.

XML code:

```
<LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/mainpageContainer"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/TextView1"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                <ListView
                    android:id="@+id/listView2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
                </ListView>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/TextView2"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                <ListView
                    android:id="@+id/listView3"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                </ListView>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/TextView3"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                <ListView
                    android:id="@+id/listView4"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
                </ListView>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/TextView4"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                <ListView
                    android:id="@+id/listView5"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
                </ListView>
            </LinearLayout>
```

Every listview will contain exactly 4 items only.
Any help guys?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use only one `ListView` and `MergeAdapter` instead of four `ListView`s. 
`MergeAdapter` accepts a mix of `Adapter`s and `View`s and presents them as one contiguous whole to whatever `ListView` it is poured into. This is good for cases where you have multiple data sources, or if you have a handful of ordinary `View`s to mix in with lists of data, or the like.

MergeAdapter library: https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-merge

Comment: thank you. till now i have fixed my problem by assigning a fixed height for the listviews since i know i only have four fixed items in each list. I will try out your solution later :)